# Trying to make SDL widget in QT4 using SDL_WINDOWID, but can't get widget to show

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, sdl

I'm trying to create an SDL drawing canvas inside of a simple QT4 window, following the information provided [in the SDL wiki](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/FAQ_GUI) and in another question on this site.  The project is an NES emulator using QT and SDL that a friend and I decided we wanted to try creating.

Currently, I have a main_window class that will contain the SDL widget, menus that I set up, and probably other stuff as the project develops.  The SDL widget I'm creating is called rom_canvas and inherits from QWidget.  So far, I'm able to set the SDL_WINDOWID environment variable and I seem to be able to interact with the widget in that I can set and get its geometry and see that it is in fact "visible", but nothing actually shows up in the window.

I don't have any experience with QT4 and SDL until now and don't have a ton of C++ experience, so I could be missing something obvious.

Here's the rom_canvas class:

```
#include "rom_canvas.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QString>

rom_canvas::rom_canvas(QWidget *parent)
 : QWidget(parent)
{
 parent->setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
 parent->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
// setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
// setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);

 setUpdatesEnabled(false);

 // a hack I found online to get the SDL surface to appear in our own window
 QString id;
 id.setNum(parent->winId());
    setenv("SDL_WINDOWID", id.toAscii().data(), 1);
 SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

 resize(320, 240);

 // change constants later
 sdl_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(320, 240, DEFAULT_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE);

 if(!sdl_screen)
  std::cout << "couldn't create screen" << std::endl;

 SDL_LockSurface(sdl_screen);
 SDL_FillRect(sdl_screen, NULL, 0x00FF0000);
 SDL_UnlockSurface(sdl_screen);
 SDL_UpdateRect(sdl_screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

rom_canvas::~rom_canvas()
{
 // do NOT release sdl_screen here; that's done when SDL_Quit() is called in main().
}

// this method is a protected slot
void rom_canvas::test()
{
 std::cout << "rom_canvas test" << std::endl;
 SDL_LockSurface(sdl_screen);
 SDL_FillRect(sdl_screen, NULL, 0x00FF0000);
 SDL_UnlockSurface(sdl_screen);
 SDL_UpdateRect(sdl_screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

And here's the main_window constructor:

```
main_window::main_window(QWidget *parent)
 : QMainWindow(parent)
{
 canvas = new rom_canvas(this);
 setCentralWidget(canvas);
 canvas->setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100);
 canvas->show();
 canvas->update();

 // Add File Menu
 open_action = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
 open_action->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Open);
 open_action->setStatusTip(tr("Open a new ROM"));
 connect(open_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(select_rom()));

 exit_action = new QAction(tr("E&xit"), this);
 exit_action->setStatusTip(tr("Exit nesT"));
 connect(exit_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), /*QApplication::instance()*/canvas, SLOT(/*quit()*/test()));
 // Remember to change this back!!

 file_menu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
 file_menu->addAction(open_action);
 file_menu->addAction(exit_action);

 rom_dir = QDir::homePath();
}
```

The code's a bit messy since I've been trying things to get this to work.  Any help is of course greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you don't have much experience in Qt or SDL, I would reconsider using both. You can probably accomplish what you want using just one of the two.

Comment: I doubt that, since SDL is not a GUI library. His problem is very interesting and I have had the sample problem with Gtkmm. I ended up using Cairo to draw freely in one Widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you already know, but the SDL_WINDOWID trick probably isn't portable - I am pretty sure it won't work on Mac. I am curious what you want SDL for, in this scenario - if you simply want a pixel-addressable image buffer (or several), use QPixmap / QImage and stick to pure Qt. Or if you want the SDL sprite features, I'd suggest having SDL composite to an in-memory buffer attached to a QImage, and then draw that to a Qt widget. (Or use QImages as sprites, and use the OpenGL QPainter backend)

Internally, Qt works pretty hard to use platform-native code to do image format conversion, so even though this sounds fairly copy-heavy, I think it will be sufficiently fast, and much more robust and portable than the SDL_WINDOWID trick.

Comment: Actually, a few days after I got SDL to show something, we (my friend and I) decided to just use Qt--partially because we were concerned about the WINDOWID trick being "fixed" in the future.  I think I'm going try having the sprite subclass from QGraphicsItem and work with a QImage in there.  This should work great since it turns out that QImage supports paletted 8-bit images.

Thanks for the help and useful info!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it to at least display something.  After playing with the code for a little bit, I ended up commenting out the `setAttribute` methods at the top of the file and it seems to be working.  Also, the `setUpdatesEnabled` method didn't seem to have an impact, so I removed that since I only had it in there when trying to get this to work.

Below is a picture of it in action.  I don't yet have code to refresh the surface, so I have to select a menu option to draw it for now.  It does appear that the menu bar is cutting top of the surface off, so I'll have to figure out how to reposition it later.

Hopefully, this helps someone.

[SDL canvas http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3453/nestsdl.png](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/3453/nestsdl.png)